# Couchbase java-client vs couchbase-client

Tags: couchbase

What is the difference between Couchbase java-client and couchbase-client?
I can see bulk get operation in java-client but not in couchbase-client
Is it possible to do bulk get operation in if we use couchbase-client?

Comment: What do you mean by "couchbase-client"? By "couchbase-java-client" I guess you are referring to Couchbase Java SDK: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For couchbase-client you refer to REST API Couchbase? 
if this its true SDK java client create connection with database directly and there are many functions to get, create and update documents
you can map document in java class and even if you want put your Example.java class directly in document in spring there are documentarion for implement this.

In other way with API you can send n1ql query the response contain the document in json format.

Depends on the implementation you want.

I recomended that you will use SDK JAVA

Good luck.